# Properties in VB

Tags: properties, vb6

Below is the snippet written in a VB .cls file :

```
Public Property Get Request() As String
    Request = m_sRequest
End Property
Public Property Let Request(sData As String)
    m_sRequest = sData
    ParseRequest sData
End Property
```

---

In another class the line below is used:

```
Public Sub LogError(Request As RequestParameters, ByVal sData As String, ibErr As CibErr)

Dim sErrorLog as string

 sErrorLog = Request("MonitorPath") & "\Log\Debug\Errors"
    If Dir(sErrorLog, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir sErrorLog
    End If

.
.
.

End Sub
```

---

I'm trying to migrate this code to C#, and I don't understand how `Request("MonitorPath")` is returning a string.

If yes - how, as `Let` does not have any return type?
If no - how does `sErrorLog = Request("MonitorPath") & "\Log\Debug\Errors"` work?

Comment: `Let` sets the value for a scalar property. Why u expect a return type ?

Comment: How does this relate, in any way, to C#?

Comment: How does that first snippet even compile? Did you mean "Set" instead of "Let"?

Comment: I was trying to port this legacy code in C# ...

Comment: Property Set is for objects
Property Let is for "normal" datatypes ...

Comment: There are too many "requests" there! "Get Request", "Let Request", "Request As RequestParameters", "Request('MonitorPath')"... Request you to provide more details

Comment: Let is assigning not returning. There is no return type for that. In vb6 the lets and gets work together. I am assuming you are using vb6 because of the .cls file.

Comment: I see: you were using vb6. Someone tagged it vb.net

Comment: Looks like there's also a `Request` function that returns a string, in that 2nd module or globally. The Request property feom the 1st snippet wouldn't be accessed without an instance of whatever class the 1st snippet is written in.

Comment: @retailcoder I suspect that additional request is the classic asp request object... in which case, we're really working with vbscript rather than vb6. They are subtly different languages.

Comment: What does the `RequestParameters` object that's being passed to the function look like?

Comment: Where does Shift+F2 take you? ...if that's VB6 it stands for "go to definition" and can be helpful in such cases.

Comment: `RequestParameters` could be a collection type here.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent C# to that old vb6 code looks like this:

```csharp
private string m_Request;
public string Request 
{
   get {return m_Request;}
   set
   {
      m_Request = value;
      ParseRequest(value);
   }
}
```

The C# equivalent to the function is this:

```csharp
public void LogError(RequestParameters Request, string Data, CibErr ibErr)
{
    // the "Request" here is a different Request than the property above
    // I have to guess a bit, but I think it's probably an indexed property
    string ErrorLog = Request["MonitorPath"] + @"\Log\Debug\Errors";

    // There is no need to check if the folder exists.
    // If it already exists, this call will just complete with no changes
    Directory.CreateDirectory(ErrorLog);

    //generally, checking for existence of items in the file system before using them is BAD
    // the file system is volatile, and so checking existence is a race condition
    // instead, you need to have good exception handling
}
```

For the type parts of the question, if you don't specify a return type for an item, the return type is `Object`. But that's just the compiler type. The actual object reference will have a more specific type that inherits from Object. In this case, that type is `String` However, since the compiler only knows about `Object` you have to turn Option Strict Off if you want to just treat the object like the string you know it really is. That's bad. So bad, that C# doesn't allow support this at all outside of the special `dynamic` keyword. Instead, you are much better off choosing specific types all the time.

Comment: The first parameter should be something like `RequestParameters Request` - note that the type and name of the variable are the other way around in Visual Basic.

Comment: @Hannele thanks for spotting that. Yeah, I just skimmed through the original too quickly.

Comment: Np. My best guess is that the `Request` being referenced in the function is, in fact, that parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just tried to implement the changes as suggested. Now facing error :                                           "Error 94 : The best overloaded method match for 'string.this[int]' has some invalid arguments. "

Comment: That's because of the naming collision between the request argument in the function and the request property in the class.

Answer (score 1):

If `Request("MonitorPath")` is in a class that does not contain  `Property Get/Get Request()` then its using a method within itself that is called `Request`. (It can't call another classes property without an instance qualification).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're conflating these two uses of `Request` - the first usage may be unrelated to the second.

Note that the function is passing in an object called `Request` - if `RequestParameters` is something like a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` (C# equivalent of `Dictionary<string, string>`), then it could very easily return a value for `Request("MonitorPath")`, and it wouldn't involve the property at all.

If that doesn't help you, what does the structure of `RequestParameters` look like?

Comment: RequestParameter is a class. Request is created as below :                           Dim Request As New RequestParameters

Comment: If you're having trouble posting it here, this would be useful information to add to the question itself!

Comment: Can you track down the definition/documentation of `RequestParameters`? Maybe something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.resourcemanagement.webservices.wsresourcemanagement.requestparameter(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: Either way, my best guess - it's the `Request` parameter that is being used in the function, not the property that you're looking at.