# What does Property Let means in VB?

Tags: properties, vb6

I have often come across code that looks like this.

```
Public Property Get MyProperty() As String
    MyProperty = m_MyProperty
End Property

Public Property Set MyProperty(ByVal value As String)
    m_MyProperty = value
End Property
```

Or even:

```
Public Property Get MyProperty() As String
    Return m_MyProperty
End Property
```

And I had never ever met with this.

```
Public Property Let MyProperty(ByVal value As String)
    m_MyProperty = value
End Property
```

Is the **Let** keyword the same as **Set** ?

According to this post, it seems so.

[**Properties in VB**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859748/properties-in-vb)

---

**MSDN** states:

[**Property Let Statement**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266197(v=vs.60).aspx)

> Declares the name, arguments, and code that form the body of a Property Let procedure, which assigns a value to a property.

[**Property Set Statement**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266202(v=vs.60).aspx)

> Declares the name, arguments, and code that form the body of a Property procedure, which sets a reference to an object.

In addition to it, as per MSDN definition:

[**Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172196.aspx)

> A named attribute of a control, field, or object that you set to define one of the object's characteristics (such as size, color, or screen location) or an aspect of its behavior (such as whether the object is hidden).

[**Object**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171792.aspx)

> Objects seen in a Microsoft Access database:
>
> - tables, queries, forms, reports, macros, and modules
> - objects that are defined by the system, such as the MSysObjects table
>
> Objects seen in a Microsoft Access project:
>
> - objects stored in the Access project file: forms, reports, macros, and modules
> - objects stored in the Microsoft SQL Server database: tables, table properties (such as > - indexes, triggers, keys, constraints, defaults, rules, and user-defined data types), views, stored procedures, and database diagrams
> - objects defined by the system, such as the sysindexes table
>
> Objects seen in both Access databases and Access projects:
>
> - data access pages, which are shortcuts (displayed in the Database window) to corresponding HTML files stored in the file system
> - information from another application, such as a chart (graph) or a drawing

Except that the context under which I have seen the **Property Let Statement** used, there is no Access or whatsoever else.

Thanks for the received comments. They guided me to MSDN, though I still can't get the meaning of the **Let** statement, apart that it might be interchangeable with the **Set** statement, as I see it.

**Are they both really interchangeable?**

Comment: Let was for variables, Set was for objects, but they may have been interchangable in Prop getters/setters

Comment: The VB6 docs say "Property Set defines a property procedure, which sets a reference to an *object*." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266202(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pretty much answered your own question.

As you can see from the MSDN docs, a `Let` declaration for a property is used to assign a **value**, i.e. to be used for any datatype *except* for objects (for which you would normally assign through `Set` anyway).

So, following the same logic, a `Set` declaration would be used if you want/need to be able to assign **objects**, and only objects (typed or not) to a property.

So, let's say you have:

```
Property Let MyFirstProperty(NewValue As String)
    m_sMyFirstProperty = NewValue
End Property

Property Set MySecondProperty(NewValue As Object)
    Set m_oMySecondProperty = NewValue
End Property
```

Then the following won't work:

```
' This won't work
MyFirstProperty = CreateObject("...")
' Neither will this
Set MyFirstProperty = CreateObject("...")
' Also, the following won't be allowed
MySecondProperty = "My new string"
```

But the following two statements will:

```
MyFirstProperty = "My new string"
Set MySecondProperty = CreateObject("...")
```

**Note** that you can have both a `Let` and `Set` declarations for the same property at the same time, depending on what you want to do:

- You could handle objects being assigned to the property **differently** (through the `Set` declare) than for other datatypes (using the `Let`);
- Or, if your internal variable for the property is a **Variant**, and you want to allow both objects and scalar values to be assigned to the property.

In short, then:

- If you want to assign **values** to a property (everything but objects), add a `Let` handler for the property.
- If you want to assign **objets** to a property, you'll need a `Set` handler for the property.

Comment: +1 For the part where you say that one may as well have both a **Let** and a **Set** for the same property depending on certain factors - and having provided an easy-to-understand sample. Sometimes one might understand something in a way and just want to make sure one understands the right thing. =)